# Adding sPagination to my jQuery datatables script causes it to stop working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

If run the code below without this line:

```
   "sPaginationType": "RequestID",
```

the code works but when that line is added, we are running into the following error:

**TypeError: DataTable.ext.oPagination[oSettings.sPaginationType] is undefined**

I do have the paginator library defined at top of page:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/dataTables.jPaginator.js"></script>
```

What else am I missing?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    /* Init DataTables */
$("#examples").dataTable( {
    "bProcessing" : true,
    "sPaginationType": "RequestID",
    // Commenting out next line
    //"sDom" : 't',
    "sAjaxSource" : "phpservices/getUserDetails.php?loginName=" + UserName,
    "sAjaxDataProp" : "",
    "bDestroy" : true,
    "fnServerData" : function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
        request = $.ajax({
            "dataType" : "json",
            "type" : "GET",
            "url" : sSource,
            "data" : aoData,
            "success" : fnCallback
        });
    },
         "aoColumns" : [
          { mDataProp: "RequestID", bSortable: true },
          { mDataProp: "RequestDate", bSortable: true },
          { mDataProp: "RequestorFullName", bSortable: true },
          { mDataProp: "PrimarySiteContactDisplay", bSortable: true },
          { mDataProp: "RequestLocation", bSortable: true },
          { mDataProp: "RequestDescription", bSortable: true },
          { mDataProp: "RequestStatus", bSortable: true },
        ],
      })
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this problem.

I neglected to change sPagination to bPagination, consistent with const definition.

from

```
"sbPaginationType": "RequestID",
```

to

```
"bPaginationType": "RequestID",
```